# Karma +Jasmine +Angular "Argument is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need to test Angular controler, but i see an error:
"Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined".

Can someone help me, i have no idea...

```js
 // file karma conf.js

     files: [
                'bower_components/angularjs/angular.js',
                'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

                'app.js',
                'controllers/*.js',
                'directives/*.js',
                'services/*.js',
                'controllers/controllersSpec.js',
        ],
```

```js
    // app.js 

       var app = angular.module('app', []);

    // controller
    angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
      function ($scope) {

        $scope.thing = 1;

     }]);
```

```js
// controllersSpec.js

describe('MainCtrl', function() {
var controller, scope;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should have scope to be defined', function() {
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();
});

});
```

Can someone help me, i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file, where `MainCtrl` is defined hasn't been loaded. Check that this file is being included in `karma.conf.js`.

Other than this, your test works: http://jsbin.com/miroqomiyo/edit?html,js,output